# String Length in Pixels

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How can I obtain the lenght of a string (given a font , size weight etc) in Pixels?  I have seen recomendations to try System.Drawing.Graphics.* but that Assembly / Namespace doesn't seem to be available to me in silverlight.

I hope to center a text box under an image, but the text is provided dynamically.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this in SL.  WPF can using the System.Drawing.Graphics classes, but as you noted they don't exist in SL and I've never found another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to Centre the TextBox don't mess around with calculating width etc. Just tell the Container to centre the textbox.

eg.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="ToolBox Avatar.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It is a good solution - but my items are on different "rows"  I should probably go back and redesign UI.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I not familiar with developing for Silverlight, I think that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28VS.71%29.aspx) might be of use to you.

Comment: Using WPF doesn't mean System.Drawing is unavailable.  You can still manually add a reference to it. (Edit: Oh wait, Silverlight, I forgot!  Maybe you can't.)